# logback does not show info level of my class

Tags: java

```
In Java:
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("application")
  logger.error("some error")
  logger.info("some info")

logback.xml:
  <logger name="application" level="INFO" />
```

this works as expected: it prints some error and some info.

However:

```
In Java, a class Application within the controllers
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class)
  logger.error("some error")
  logger.info("some info")

logback.xml:
  <logger name="controllers.Application" level="INFO" />

I get:
   2016-07-17 11:14:07,888 - [ERROR] - from controllers.Application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38 
   some error
```

I only get some error, but not some info.
why?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? As is there's too litlle information so it's hard to help you. You should also specify what "log4back" is, I've never heard of that, log4j/log4j2 and logback are usual things however

Comment: Can we show the whole logback conf file ? May be a conflict.

Comment: it is the default logging configuration for a playframework application: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger#default-configuration

Comment: i am testing this example scala application: https://github.com/lashford/modern-web-template/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala

Comment: i meant logback, not log4back. i've corrected the question.

Comment: What Application.class are you using to define your logging? What are you importing in your code? What is the package?
Can you show the complete sample?

Comment: the complete sample is here: https://github.com/lashford/modern-web-template/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala